# Bootstrap 4 accordian Not working properly with routerLink?

Tags: angular, accordion, angular-routing, bootstrap-accordion

```
 <div id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                      <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                          <h5 class="mb-0">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne" [routerLink]="['home-loan']" routerLinkActive="active">
                              Home Loan
                            </a>
                          </h5>
                        </div>

                        <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                          <div class="card-block">
                           <app-home-loan></app-home-loan>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
                          <h5 class="mb-0">
                            <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo" [routerLink]="['reduce-home-loan']" routerLinkActive="active">
                              Home Loan Balance Transfer
                            </a>
                          </h5>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
                          <div class="card-block">
                            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. 
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingThree">
                          <h5 class="mb-0">
                            <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree" [routerLink]="['personal-loan']"routerLinkActive="active">
                              Personal Loan
                            </a>
                          </h5>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
                          <div class="card-block">
                            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. 
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingThree">
                          <h5 class="mb-0">
                            <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFour" [routerLink]="['reduce-personal-loan']"routerLinkActive="active">
                              Personal Loan Transfer
                            </a>
                          </h5>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
                          <div class="card-block">
                            Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. 
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

This is my html.When i give router link to all the accordian title it is showing the content of only one item.That is home-loan content of accordian.Routing is happening in the router link as given,but the content of accordian is not showing by clicking.
Only by default home loan content is showing.This problem came only after adding roueterLink.
Please give a solution for this.Thanks in advance.